# Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '14/Oct/2016 23:09:25.2110 +0530' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, datetime

I was just playing with Java 8 Date time API.

My code looks like this.

```
LocalDateTime date=LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("date now:"+date);
String ormat = ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
//=date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss.SX Z"));
LocalDateTime date2=LocalDateTime.parse(format);

System.out.println("dsate now:"+date2);
```

But it is showing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '14/Oct/2016 23:13:57' could not be parsed at index 0
```

I tried with this pattern

```
String format=ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS Z"));
```

Still didn't work.

I checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069370/format-a-date-using-the-new-date-time-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string).

Edit:
One thing also I want to know what if I want my date object only in this format?

Edit 2:
What I try to achieve is that have some date and time what I got using localDateTime and I want to format it using the formatter I have used in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format2 produces the String `14/Oct/2016 23:26:38`

You try to parse that input String with the ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME (yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss). That is why you were getting the error.

You have to pass the date formatter  to the parse method

```
LocalDateTime date2=LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("date now:"+date2);
String format2=ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(format2);
//=date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss.SX Z"));
LocalDateTime date3=LocalDateTime.parse(format2,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));

System.out.println("dsate now:"+date3);
```

Output:

```
dsate now:2016-10-14T23:26:38
```

Edit after the comment:

You can directly format the LocalDateTime

```
LocalDateTime date2=LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("date now:"+date2);
String myDate1 = date2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println("dsate now:"+myDate1);
```

Comment: ok it works but why do I need then format 2 if I am again formatting in 3rd step? again this is out of scope of this question but what should I do if I want to format my date2 only/?

Comment: You don't. You can use String myDate1 = date2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));

Comment: Have updated my question based on your answer please see once

Comment: You want date2 as 14/Oct/2016 23:26:38 instead of 2016-10-14T23:26:38?

Comment: What you see in System.out.println(date2) is toString() of LocalDateTime.  That is why you were able to see the date in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125739/discussion-between-vihang-shah-and-unknown).