# How to convert String date to date and set own format in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have following date in String.

```
"2022-02-01T20:32:00.000Z"
```

And i want to format this date to following pattern

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a
```

I tried following solution from another StackOverflow question.

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2022-02-01T20:32:00.000Z", inputFormatter);
String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); //02/01/2022
```

but this format gives only date and i want to time with date. so i added time format in pattern like this.

```
1.
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

2.
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a").withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());;
```

but it gives me following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: HourOfDay
```

So how can i achieve `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"` pattern from `"2022-02-01T20:32:00.000Z"` string date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a date using the new date time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069370/format-a-date-using-the-new-date-time-api)

Comment: A tip for you: paste our error message into your search engine and find the answer immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with two lines as this :

```
OffsetDateTime offset = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-02-01T20:32:00.000Z");
String output = offset.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
```

Output

```
02/01/2022 08:32:00 PM
```

---

Your string `"2022-02-01T20:32:00.000Z"` is formatted as the default format of `OffsetDateTime`, so all you need to do is to convert it to `OffsetDateTime` and then use another formatter to get the desired output.

As you are using `a` in the end of your pattern, I would suggest to use `hh` instead of `HH`.

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L. Yes, i changed hh from HH.

Comment: The original string is in UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`). One would probably want to convert to the user’s time zone for printing.