# UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: HourOfDay in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know the remaining d-day by calculating a specific date received from the server from the current date.
I wrote the code in the following way, but I got an error.
How cam I solve this problem?

```
        val date = "2021-05-10T10:00:00.000Z"
        val inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    val outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    val formateDate : LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(date, inputFormatter)
                    val formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(formateDate)
                    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

                    val targetDate = format.parse(formattedDate)

                    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
                    val result = (today.time.time - targetDate.time) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)

                    tv_remaining_date.text = "$result"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a date using the new date time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069370/format-a-date-using-the-new-date-time-api)