# Getting Unsupported field: DayOfMonth while using DateTimeFormatter in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time

Exact error: **java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth**

Below is a HashMap I've created where we can see only 3 months of data are present. The end goal is to create/update the MAP dynamically with last 12 moths of data, from current month.

Any month other than these 3 months will have value as 0L.

```
Map<String, Long> expectedValues = new HashMap<>();
expectedValues.put("2021-06-01", 10L);
expectedValues.put("2021-07-01", 20L);
expectedValues.put("2021-08-01", 30L);
```

I have written this logic to check and populate 0L for non-existing months. However getting the error while using the **DateTimeFormatter**

```java
YearMonth thisMonth = YearMonth.now();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    String prevYearMonthStr = thisMonth.minusMonths(i).format(monthYearFormatter);
    if (!expectedValues.containsKey(prevYearMonthStr)) {
        expectedValues.put(prevYearMonthStr, 0L);
    }
}
```

How can we fix this error.

Comment: A `YearMonth` doesn't have a day, so you can't use a formatter which wants one.

Comment: Are you sure you want the map key of `expectedValues` to be a `String`? Of course, it depends on your exact use case, but in general, I would have used a `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: @MC Emperor Yeah the use case requires it to be String.

Comment: You are using a `String` that represents a full date (`LocalDate`) with year, month of year and day of month, but a `YearMonth` does not have a day of month. Can't you use `String`s like `"2021-06"` instead and parse them using a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM")`?

Comment: No I need in the format of "2021-08-01". Is there any package other than YearMonth which can serve the purpose ?

Comment: Related/similar: [Format a date using the new date time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069370/format-a-date-using-the-new-date-time-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `YearMonth` has only a year and a month field. Then you are trying to format it using an `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` formatter, which expects the `Temporal` (in your case `YearMonth`) to support a day-of-month field.

That obviously won't work.

You could use `YearMonth`'s `atDay` method, which converts the `YearMonth` to a `LocalDate` with the specified day-of-month. Next, this `LocalDate` can be formatted using the predefined `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` formatter, which is equal to a formatter with the pattern string `uuuu-MM-dd`.

```java
YearMonth thisMonth = YearMonth.now();
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    String prev = thisMonth.minusMonths(i).atDay(1).format(format);
    if (!expectedValues.containsKey(prev)) {
        expectedValues.put(prev, 0L);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/fDNzgn)</kbd>

Or using Java 8 features:

```java
static Map<String, Long> transform(Map<String, Long> expectedValues) {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    return Stream.iterate(YearMonth.now(), ym -> ym.minusMonths(1))
        .limit(12)
        .map(ym -> ym.atDay(1).format(format))
        .map(str -> Map.entry(str, expectedValues.getOrDefault(str, 0L)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

This is what happens here:

- `Stream::iterate` accepts an initial value, which is the current month, and then iterates over each month in the past.
- `limit` makes sure we have 12 values, otherwise we would have an infinite stream.
- The first `map` converts the `YearMonth` to a `LocalDate` with the first day of the month. Then it formats it using the pattern `uuuu-MM-dd`.
- The second `map` creates a `Map.Entry` with the stream element as key, and as value either the value from the `expectedValues` map, or `0L` if the key doesn't exist. Of course, these two `map` calls could be merged.
- Then we collect these `Map.Entry<String, Long>` elements currently contained in the stream, to a `Map`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/ulAKh3)</kbd>

Comment: I have tried the first solution, it is throwing this error now - Unsupported field: HourOfDay.

Comment: @sandeep You are using `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`, while in my example, I use `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.